# Why does angular.isNumber(NaN) return true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nan

NaN represents Not-A-Number.

It appears that angular.isNumber thinks it is a number.  (angularjs 1.4.2)
Why does angular.isNumber return true for NaN input?

thanks

Comment: Show us a full code sample so we can help more

Comment: What else would NaN be if not a number?

Comment: man i'm totally a number

Comment: Very much related: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/701

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [IgorMinar](https://github.com/IgorMinar), Angular Developer in this exact [question](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/701):

> ```
> $ node
> > typeof NaN
> 'number'
> ```
>
> It kind of makes sense if you squint with both eyes and plug your
>   ears.
>
> If you deliberately use NaN in your app, you should use isNaN instead
>   of angular.isNumber.
>
> I'm inclined to say that the current behavior, even though a bit
>   surprising, **is consistent with how NaN is being treated in javascript**.
>   If you have some good arguments for changing the behavior please share
>   them with us.

So the question really goes for the javascript standard itself not for Angular

And to answer this question we must go to [ECMAScript 5 specification of number type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.20), of course it says:

> **4.3.20 Number type**
>
> set of all possible Number values **including the special “Not-a-Number”**
>   **(NaN) values**, positive infinity, and negative infinity
>
> **4.3.23 NaN**
>
> **number value** that is a IEEE 754 “Not-a-Number” value

So yes, according to the latest [ECMAScript Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) i'm a number

Comment: Easily the best answer here - it's rare you're able to answer a question in the form of "I'm using library <X>, why does it behave like this?" definitively. +1

Comment: OMFG @NaN you're so a number, i don't understand what is the confusion in this

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer

Comment: username checks out

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best way that I can think of to explain this.

Although the value of `NaN` represents *something* that is not a number, the value `NaN` itself is still a number *type* (in the type system sense).

It's also a defined value for a floating point number in IEEE 754, which is what JavaScript uses for numbers. It is sensible that values infinity and NaN would be number types.

Answer (score 1):

The [ECMA spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23) defines NaN as a IEEE 754 Not-a-Number number value. One reason for the [`NaN` global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) being a number are comparison purposes. It is also needed to represent undefined numerical results, like the value of `Math.sqrt(-1)`. So it’s not particularly AngularJS specific. Consider the following:

```
typeof NaN === "number"   // true
typeof NaN === typeof NaN // true
typeof NaN === typeof 123 // true
NaN === NaN  // false
isNaN(NaN)   // true
isNaN(123)   // false
isNaN('123') // false
isNaN('|23') // true
```

So `isNumber` returns true for `NaN` because it is a `Number`. To check for numerics, use [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

Answer (score 0):

it's not related to angular, it's `JavaScript`
try this

```
typeof NaN
```

it will return `number`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely angular just uses the type of what you pass in. if the type is number then it returns true.

If you want to know if something is a number (excluding NaN) you can do the following.

```
function isNumber(val){
  return angular.isNumber(val) && (val == val);
}
```

This works by first determing if val is a number. If it is check to see if it's NaN.

NaN is not equal to itself (or any other number for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

There are really two meanings of "number" here:

- the abbreviation "NaN" means that there is no meaningful answer to a particular mathematical operation; you could say "no such number"
- however, every value in a language like JS has a type, and the type of data which goes into and out of mathematical operations is known in JS as "number"; thus when JS wants a special value to say that a mathematical operation has no answer, that special value is a special number

Note that this apparent contradiction is less obvious in other languages, because JS is unusual in having only one numeric type, rather than (at least) integer and real/float types. Having NaN as a floating point value is standard across pretty much all modern languages, but because of the word "number", it perhaps seems more surprising in JS.

The Angular function is one of a set of utilities for testing the type of a value. [The documentation for it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber) mentions that it returns true for infinities and NaN, and points to the standard `isFinite` function for when that's not desirable.